# Tailwind CSS - how to make a grid with two columns where the 1st column has 20% of the width and 2nd one 80% width?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

From the official documentation, I am only able to come up with something like this:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3">
  <div>1st col</div>
  <div>2nd col</div>
</div>
```

But this gives me 2 columns with an equal width - how do I specify that the first column would be like 20% of the total width (I only need to place there a simple icon) and the rest of the width would be the second column (here would be a text)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Set `grid-cols-5` to the wrapper and `col-span-4` to second column. It will cover `4/5 (80%)`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<div class="grid grid-cols-5 gap-3">
  <div class="bg-blue-100">1st col</div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-span-4">2nd col</div>
</div>
```

Another way with `grid-flow-col`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<div class="grid grid-flow-col gap-3">
  <div class="bg-blue-100 col-span-1">1st col</div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-span-4">2nd col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @dogukan. I am just wondering - I used the 20-80% width ratio as an example, what if I need one column to be like 40px and the other one 260px? Can I still use the grid system here?

Answer (score 24):

You can define additional utilities by extending the theme in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns:
      {
        '20/80': '20% 80%',
        'fixed': '40px 260px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-20/80 w-full h-64">
  <div class="bg-blue-500"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-500"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-cols-fixed h-64">
  <div class="bg-blue-500"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-500"></div>
</div>
```

---

Updated for Tailwind CSS 3:

With the introduction of the JIT compiler and the ability to use arbitrary/dynamic values in some utilities,  you can now do this without the config:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-[20%_80%] w-full h-64">
```

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-[40px_260px] w-full h-64">
```

Comment: UV for coming back and adding details for TW v3 arbitrary values.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `col-span` like below

```
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5 gap-3"> // This will create 5 grids so 20% each
      <div class="some-class"></div>
      <div class="col-span-4"></div> // This will take 80% of space
    </div>
```

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column#class-reference

Comment: @doğukan yes you just added the answer one minute before while i was writing code. and its not exactly same. you can check.

Answer (score 7):

Simple

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="w-1/5"> 20% </div>
  <div class="w-4/5"> 80% </div>
</div>
```

https://v1.tailwindcss.com/components/flexbox-grids

Answer (score 4):

further to [@horuskol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184124)'s solution for column templates, `%` doesn't respect the container dimensions so if you use `gap` then the grid will overflow it's container

if instead of `%` you use [`fr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex_value) then the grid contents will be styled flexibly and so not overflow the container

eg.

`grid-cols-[1fr_2fr]` gives 2 cols at 33% / 66%

`grid-cols-[1fr_2fr_1fr]` gives 3 cols at 25% / 50% / 25%